# Difficulty adding AdMob Native Ads in Android Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob

how are you? I am trying to add Google AdMob native ads to a recyclerview feed. I followed the instructions provided by the Google Developer Codelabs here. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed-android/#0. It mostly worked. I have the ads inserted and posts being displayed. But the problem is, I think, the number of total items to be displayed, my app's posts plus the ads. I'm testing it, so there are only four posts to be displayed plus one native ad. But the feed is only returning three posts plus the one ad. Here is the Home Activity:

```
private PostAdapter postAdapter;
private List<Post> postList;
private List<String> followingList;
List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems = new ArrayList<>();

public static final int NUMBER_OF_ADS = 1;

    // The AdLoader used to load ads.
    private AdLoader adLoader;

    // List of native ads that have been successfully loaded.
    private List<UnifiedNativeAd> mNativeAds = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        mContext = HomeActivity.this;

        setupRecyclerView();
        loadNativeAds();
    }

    private void insertAdsInMenuItems() {
        if (mNativeAds.size() <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        int offset = (mRecyclerViewItems.size() / mNativeAds.size()) + 1;
        Log.d(TAG, "insertAdsInMenuItems: m native ads value: " + mNativeAds);
        Log.d(TAG, "insertAdsInMenuItems: post list value: " + postList);
        Log.d(TAG, "insertAdsInMenuItems: offset value: " + offset);
        int index = 0;
        for (UnifiedNativeAd ad: mNativeAds) {
            mRecyclerViewItems.add(index, ad);
            index = index + offset;
            Log.d(TAG, "insertAdsInMenuItems: index value: " + index);
        }
    }

    private void loadNativeAds() {

        AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(this, getString(R.string.ad_mob_native_ad_id));
        adLoader = builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(
                new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                        // A native ad loaded successfully, check if the ad loader has finished loading
                        // and if so, insert the ads into the list.
                        mNativeAds.add(unifiedNativeAd);
                        if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                            insertAdsInMenuItems();
                        }
                    }
                }).withAdListener(
                new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                        // A native ad failed to load, check if the ad loader has finished loading
                        // and if so, insert the ads into the list.
                        Log.e("MainActivity", "The previous native ad failed to load. Attempting to"
                                + " load another.");
                        if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                            insertAdsInMenuItems();
                        }
                    }
                }).build();

        // Load the Native Express ad.
        adLoader.loadAds(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), NUMBER_OF_ADS);
    }

private void setupRecyclerView(){
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_posts);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        postList = new ArrayList<>();
        postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getApplicationContext(), postList, mRecyclerViewItems);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

        checkFollowing();
    }

    private void checkFollowing(){
        Log.d(TAG, "checkFollowing: compile following list...");
        followingList = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("following").child(currentUserID);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                followingList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    followingList.add(snapshot.getKey());
                    Log.d(TAG, "checkFollowing: following list array" + followingList);
                }

                displayPosts();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void displayPosts(){
        Log.d(TAG, "displayPosts: running....");
        allPostsReference.orderByKey().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    try{
                        Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                        for (String id : followingList){
                            if (post.getUser_id().equals(id)){
                                postList.add(post);
                            }
                        }try{
                            if (post.getUser_id().equals(currentUserID)){
                                postList.add(post);
                            }
                        }catch (NullPointerException e){
                            e.getMessage();
                        }

                        int postCount = (int)dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                        Log.d(TAG, "displayPosts: post count of my timeline: " + postCount);
                    }catch (NullPointerException e){
                        e.getMessage();
                    }catch (DatabaseException e){
                        e.getMessage();
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

That's how I am adding the native ads to mRecyclerViewItems and all of the posts to postList. The checkFollowing method is displaying only posts of those I am following, which at this point, is all of the posts in the Firebase Realtime Database. And this is the relevant portions of the Post Adapter class:

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "PostAdapter";

    // A menu item view type.
    private static final int MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;

    // The unified native ad view type.
    private static final int UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

    public Context mContext;
    public List<Post> mPost;
    public List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems;

    public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Post> mPost, List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mPost = mPost;
        this.mRecyclerViewItems = mRecyclerViewItems;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType){
            case UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                View unifiedNativeLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(
                        parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_native_express_ad_container, parent, false);
                return new UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder(unifiedNativeLayoutView);

            case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                //fall through

            default:
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_post_item, parent, false);
                return new PostViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        switch (viewType){
            case UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd) mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);
                populateNativeAdView(nativeAd, ((UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder) holder).getAdView());
                break;

            case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                //follow through

            default:
                final PostViewHolder postViewHolder = (PostViewHolder) holder;
                Post post = (Post) mPost.get(position);
                final String postKey = post.getPost_key();

                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                publicUserReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("public_user");
                allPostsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("all_posts");

                //some sample methods
                postViewHolder.setInitialLayouts(postKey);
                mVotes.setTextForVoteButtons(postKey, postViewHolder.voteOne, postViewHolder.voteTwo, postViewHolder.voteThree, postViewHolder.voteFour);
                postViewHolder.getProfilephotoFullnameUsername(postKey);
                postViewHolder.getVoteText(postKey);
                postViewHolder.getDate(postKey);
                postViewHolder.displayPhoto(postKey);
}

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPost.size() + mRecyclerViewItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        try{
            Object recyclerViewItem = mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);
            if (recyclerViewItem instanceof UnifiedNativeAd) {
                return UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
            }
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
```

Sorry if that's a lot of code, I am just kind of confused. Like I said, only three of my four posts in the database are being returned. It's as if the native ad is taking its place instead of being added into the feed along with the post items. Is there something I am missing? Should I be sending something different from Home Activity to the Post Adapter? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So you have `List<Post>` and `Ads` two types of Data need to present into a single `RecyclerView` .So now you need to merge both data into 1 single data source to be used in the `RecyclerView`.

**Here is the example:**

**First**: Create a data class that combine `Post` and `Ads` named `PostAdsData`:

```
public class PostAdsData {
    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public UnifiedNativeAd getAds() {
        return ads;
    }

    public Post getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public int type; // 1 is ads and 2 is post
    public UnifiedNativeAd ads;
    public Post post;
}
```

**Second:** Your adapter should look like this:

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    // A menu item view type.
    private static final int MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;

    // The unified native ad view type.
    private static final int UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

    public List<PostAdsData> postAdsDataList;

    public PostAdapter(Context mContext) {
       this.context = mContext;
    }

    public void setPostAdsDataList(List<PostAdsData> postAdsData){ // we set the data for the recyclerView here 
        this.postAdsDataList = postAdsData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            // here do your thing as usual 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

        switch (viewType){
            // here switch viewType as usual,but refer the data from postAdsDataList
        }

     }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(postAdsDataList.get(position).getType() == 1){
            return  UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
        }else{
            return MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (postAdsDataList != null) {
            return postAdsDataList.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Third: In your `HomeActivity`, so here is the place you need to set the data(Post) into the `RecyclerView`,you need to "transform" the data inside `List<Post>` to `List<PostAdsData>` like this:

```
private void displayContent(List<Post> posts){

    List<PostAdsData> postAdsDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Post item : posts) {
        PostAdsData data = new PostAdsData();
        data.ads = null;
        data.post = item;
        data.type = 2; // here 1 for ads, 2 will be post
        postAdsDataList.add(data);
    }

    yourAdapter.setPostAdsDataList(postAdsDataList); // here set in the Posts data into the recyclerView
}
```

`displayContent()` function above should be called after you get the data from Firebase I assumed.So it will look like this:

```
private void displayPosts(){

    //ALL OTHER STUFF 
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       for(....){
         // after your for loop
         // then all the Post will added inside the List<Post>
       }

       // then we called  here 
       displayContent(postList) // your postList
    }
}
```

So now we done insert the `posts`. Therefore, when you get the `UnifiedNativeAd` from Google Admob,we also need to "transform" `UnifiedNativeAd` to `postAdsData` object,like this:

```
// add this to YourAdapter class 
public void insertAdsToRecyclerView(UnifiedNativeAd ad){ // if more than 1 ads,then here should be a list,and use for loop at the code below

    PostAdsData adsData = new PostAdsData();
    adsData.post = null;
    adsData.ads = ad;
    adsData.type = 1;

    postAdsDataList.add(0,adsData); // here will add the ads to the 1st item of the list
    notifyItemInserted(0);
}
```

Then in your `insertAdsInMenuItems()` will become like this:

```
private void insertAdsInMenuItems() {
   postAdapter.insertAdsToRecyclerView(mNativeAds.get(0))// cause i seen you request for 1 ad only
}
```

Hope you get the idea.Now we successfully merge both `Post` and `Ad` into 1 data source.So it will easier for us to present in `RecylerView`.

Comment: and where should load the ads!

Comment: @MostafaOnaizan loads ads after initialize the recyclerview. when the ads done loading, you insert the ads into the PostAdsData array, then ` notifyItemInserted` for the recyclerview, so the recyclerview can be updated

Comment: But I can only load 5 ads what if myrecycleview endless and I want to load an ad every 4 items

Comment: @MostafaOnaizan step by step, dont think of load all the ads in the beginning. What you can do is, when the recyclerview reach the end, by adding `addOnScrollListener` to the recyclerview( (example visible item is last 3 item) then u load the native ads again, then insert back to the array.

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't think of it like this